# Amazon S3 Bucket: Not able to to upload the data to a specific S3 bucket

Tags: android, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

The issue I am facing is that, I have a task to upload images,video, audio and pdf files to a S3 bucket.
This code resides in my activity:

```
    S3Credentials s3Credentials = new S3Credentials(ACCESS_KEY,
            SECRET_KEY, "");
    S3BucketData s3BucketData = new S3BucketData.Builder()
            .setCredentials(s3Credentials)
            .setBucket(bucket)
            .setKey(uploadToS3.getName())
            .setRegion("us-west-2")
            .build();

    S3UploadService.upload(MainActivity.this, s3BucketData, uploadToS3, false);
```

The following code is used to upload data to S3 bucket:

```
if (intent == null) return;
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (!ACTION_UPLOAD.equals(action)) return;

    S3BucketData s3BucketData = (S3BucketData) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_S3_BUCKET_DATA);
    File file = (File) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_FILE);
    boolean deleteFileAfter = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_DELETE_FILE, true);
    S3Callback s3Callback = (S3Callback) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_S3_CALLBACK);
    handleUpload(s3BucketData, file, deleteFileAfter, s3Callback);

 private void handleUpload(S3BucketData s3BucketData, File file, boolean deleteFileAfter, S3Callback s3Callback) {

    TransferManager transferManager = setUpAmazonClient(s3BucketData);
    PutObjectRequest request = buildPor(s3BucketData, file, deleteFileAfter);
    AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
    acl.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.AllUsers, Permission.Read);
    acl.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.AllUsers, Permission.Write);
    request.withAccessControlList(acl);

    Upload upload = transferManager.upload(request);

    try {
        upload.waitForCompletion();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AmazonS3Exception s3e) {
        // Possible Bad Digest. Retry
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.w(TAG, "AmazonS3Exception. retrying.");
            Log.d(TAG, s3e.toString());
        }
    }


    if (s3Callback == null) return;

    Intent intent = new Intent(s3Callback.getActionCallback());
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SERIALIZABLE, s3Callback.getExtra());
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}


 private TransferManager setUpAmazonClient(S3BucketData s3BucketData) {
    System.setProperty(getString(R.string.s3_system_property), "true");
    S3Credentials s3Credentials = s3BucketData.getS3Credentials();
    BasicAWSCredentials basicSessionCredentials =
            new BasicAWSCredentials(s3Credentials.getAccessKey(),
                    s3Credentials.getSecretKey());

    ClientConfiguration s3Config = new ClientConfiguration();
    s3Config.setSocketTimeout(600000);
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(basicSessionCredentials, s3Config);

    TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(s3Client);

    Region region = Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(s3BucketData.getRegion()));


    transferManager.getAmazonS3Client().setRegion(region);
    return transferManager;
}

private PutObjectRequest buildPor(S3BucketData s3BucketData, final File file, final boolean deleteFileAfter) {

    final String bucket = s3BucketData.getBucket();
    final String key = s3BucketData.getKey();

    final PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, file);
    por.setGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
        final String url = String.format(getString(R.string.s3_format_url), bucket, key);
        private long uploadStartTime;

        @Override
        public void progressChanged(com.amazonaws.event.ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
            try {
                if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.STARTED_EVENT_CODE) {
                    uploadStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                } else if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == com.amazonaws.event.ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE) {
                    long uploadDurationMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - uploadStartTime;
                    int bytesPerSecond = (int) (file.length() / (uploadDurationMillis / 1000.0));
                    if (VERBOSE) {
                        double fileSize = file.length() / 1000.0;
                        double uploadDuration = uploadDurationMillis;
                        double uploadSpeed = bytesPerSecond / 1000.0;
                        Log.i(TAG, String.format(S3UploadService.this.getString(R.string.s3_format_uploaded), fileSize, uploadDuration, uploadSpeed));
                    }

                    if (deleteFileAfter) {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                } else if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.FAILED_EVENT_CODE) {
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.e(TAG, String.format(S3UploadService.this.getString(R.string.s3_format_upload_failed), url));
                }
            } catch (Exception excp) {
                if (VERBOSE) Log.e(TAG, "ProgressListener error");
                excp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
    return por;
}

public static void setVerbose(boolean verbose) {
    S3UploadService.VERBOSE = verbose;
}
```

I am able to upload data to two of my S3 buckets using above code. 
But, there is one bucket in which I am getting following error when trying to upload the data:
**"*The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: 69D73B8CE65BE315), S3 Extended Request ID: 54FOeNuCsR/QZxV19vcAi9RCEyNkbxuIGt5xDi8QjsZw17qwsenRF1mqZUSX3LJF1ThydZJVxIM=*”**